# Rerender after apex:detail with inlineEdit is saved

Tags: visualforce, rerender, inline, detail-page

#### The problem

I would like to give the user access to an `<apex:detail>` with inline editing enabled and let them modify the record.  I also want to show a few fields from that record nearby.  When the record is updated through the `detail` page, I want the fields to stay up to date.

Based on reading similar posts, it seems that the problem has to do with not requerying the records.  Is there a way to do this without a controller or will I have to implement a controller just for this purpose?

#### What I've tried

I assumed that `rerender` would be my ticket, but it seems not.  I'm confused by how `rerender` on `<apex:detail>` is supposed to work.  According to the documentation:

> This attribute only works if inlineEdit or showChatter are set to true.

I am writing a page with a list of a parent's child Cases.  In this simplified version, I display each child's `Priority`.  Then I provide a `<apex:detail>` component with inline editing enabled to allow the user to edit the first child.  I set the `rerender` attribute on `<apex:detail>` to the id of the list of `Priority` strings.

#### Steps to reproduce

In the `<apex:detail>`, the user changes `Priority` from Medium to Low and press Save.

#### Expected Behavior

The `<apex:outputPanel>` with `id="caseList"` is refreshed and the first child Case's `Priority` now shows as "Low".

#### Actual Behavior

The first child Case's displayed `Priority` remains "Medium".

#### Code

I have the following in my VF page (standard controller):

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Case">
  <apex:outputPanel styleClass="case-list" layout="block" id="caseList" style="float:none;">
    <ol>
      <apex:repeat var="child" value="{!case.Cases}">
        <li>{!child.Priority}</li>
      </apex:repeat>
    </ol>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:detail rerender="caseList" 
               id="childDetail" subject="{!case.Cases[0].Id}" 
               inlineEdit="true" relatedListHover="true" 
               title="false"
               >
  </apex:detail>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Does the steps to reproduce include clicking the save button after editing? Did you click out of the field before clicking save?

Comment: @Eric Yes.  I fixed that.  The data is just fine.

Comment: sry, stupid question I know, sometimes its the simplest things tough

Comment: Can you try having on change event just something simple like onChange="console.debug('hi');" ... if this works you can rerender via some Javascript.
Did you query the database to make sure the record is updated?

Comment: @AmrIbrahim onChange on what element?  And more importantly, how do you rerender through JS?

Comment: OnChange on the apex:detail and you can rerender via apex:actionSupport

Comment: @AmrIbrahim Thank you.  Your answer is about halfway there and got me where I needed to be.  I'd like to give you rep for your help.  Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be ideal, but I got somewhere that works.

After trying out [Amr Ibrahim](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/21573/amr-ibrahim)'s [advice](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/89394/rerender-after-apexdetail-with-inlineedit-is-saved?noredirect=1#comment118506_89394), I used an `<apex:actionFunction>` element which re-renders the `outputPanel`.  On the `<apex:detail>`'s `oncomplete` event, I call the JS method the `actionFunction` generates (the `<apex:actionFunction>` tag must be embedded in a `<apex:form>`).

So my changes were:

- added an `<apex:form>`
- added an `<apex:actionFunction>`
- removed the `rerender` from the `<apex:detail>`
- added an `oncomplete` attribute to the `<apex:detail>`

My resulting Visualforce that is working properly is something along these lines:

```html
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardController="Case">
  <apex:outputPanel styleClass="case-list" layout="block" id="caseList">
    <ol>
      <apex:repeat var="child" value="{!case.Cases}">
        <li>{!child.Priority}</li>
      </apex:repeat>
    </ol>
  </apex:outputPanel>

  <apex:form>
    <apex:actionFunction reRender="caseList" name="refresh" >
    </apex:actionFunction>
  </apex:form>

  <apex:detail oncomplete="refresh()" 
               id="childDetail" subject="{!case.Cases[0].Id}" 
               inlineEdit="true" relatedListHover="true" 
               title="false"
               >
  </apex:detail>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, even if you're willing to modify the controller, this is the only way to refresh a panel outside of the detail view on save.  It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Charles ... glad I helped. You can use Javascript events on the apex:detail (starting with something simple like console.debug('message') to make sure it triggers required events), then use  to rerender components.